When merging JSON objects with same keys, how do I append their values?
I have two arrays as shown below, as i concat both the arrays - the ST key value in Array1 is replaced by values in ST key values in Array2,
Array 1:
{"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp"], "OSS": ["Class"]}

Array 2:
{"ST": ["Pro", "SU"]}" 

Expected output:
{"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp","Pro", "SU"], "OSS": ["Class"]}

How do I achieve this?

Please review [mre]. Update the post with actual code that demonstrates the problem. It appears you are trying to merge array elements in JSON, but your description doesn't explicitly state this.


You need to be specific about what you are working with. The examples look like JSON objects with JSON arrays as the value for the key. This is not the same as a Postgres native ARRAY type. 2) If it is the Postgres JSON(B) then you need to read JSON Functions.


The question seems to be about  '{"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp"]}'::jsonb || '{"ST": ["Pro", "SU"]}'::jsonb using the second value instead of merging. This is documented behavior of ||.

The following will perform the requested operation:
WITH demo AS (
    SELECT
      '{"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp"], "OSS": ["Class"]}'::jsonb AS array1,
      '{"ST": ["Pro", "SU"]}'::jsonb AS array2
  )
SELECT
  array1 || JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('ST', (array1 -> 'ST') || (array2 -> 'ST'))
FROM
  demo;

The expression works by creating a new ST element from the concatenated array values from the original ST elements and then
takes advantage of the || operator's behavior of keeping the last value assigned to a common named element to create the final JSON.
The || operator isn't valid for JSON, so it will be necessary to cast any JSON elements to JSONB.

WITH js AS (
    SELECT
        '{"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp"], "OSS": ["Class"]}'::jsonb AS js_data
    )
SELECT
    jsonb_set(js_data, '{ST}', 
             jsonb_path_query_array(
                js_data, '($.ST[*])') || '["Pro", "SU"]'::jsonb)
FROM
    js
;

jsonb_set                           
--------------------------------------------------------------
 {"ST": ["Bin", "No", "Comp", "Pro", "SU"], "OSS": ["Class"]}


This uses jsonb_path_query_array to pull the existing array value from the "ST" then concatenates it to the array being merged(jsonb_path_query_array). Then jsonb_set replaces the current array associated with the "ST" key with the new merged array created in jsonb_path_query_array. The CTE(WITH) is used to not have to repeat the entire jsonb object.
